# Where is NoRowMessage in SSRS Chart Property

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to set the `NoRowMessage` Property in SSRS Chart but cannot get to it. Is it available or how do I get to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoRowMessage` is for table, matrix, list or subreport. For Chart you can use `NoDataMessage`.

1. In Design view, click the chart on the design surface to select it.The Properties pane displays the properties for the selected item.
2. In the Properties pane, expand the node for `NoDataMessage`.
3. In Caption, type the text that you want to display as a message in
   `NoDataMessage` property field.

Alternatively, from the drop-down list, click Expression to open the Expression dialog box and create an expression.